# how to place a suspended object with surf

Tags: matlab, 3d

I am writing a code to produce a house with a given height, width, length, and angle of sloped roof.

I was able to produce the walls with surf by using a zero value for a specific dimension, allowing a wall to be made as an x-y plane, x-z plane, etc.

However, Now I am trying to produce a desk inside that is an x-y plane with a specific height, and cant figure out how..

MATLAB says it needs a matrix, but a matrix formed only from the height doesn't work, also using ndgrid(heightValue:.5:heightValue) doesn't work

If anyone knows how to help, I would greatly appreciate it.

#### Code:

(one of the desk sides is in the wrong place as well for similar problems, but help with this problem will allow me to figure out how to fix it)

```
clear; clc; close all;

%% INPUT VARIABLES

lengthdlg = 'Please enter length of base (m): ';
widthdlg = 'Please enter width of base (m): ';
heightdlg = 'Please enter height of wall (m): ';
angledlg = 'Please enter the angle of the roof (degrees): ';

dlgbox = inputdlg({lengthdlg, widthdlg, heightdlg, angledlg},...
    'Simple AutoCAD', [1 50; 1 50; 1 50; 1 50], {'30','40','15','30'});

BaseL = str2double(dlgbox(1));
BaseW = str2double(dlgbox(2));
WallH = str2double(dlgbox(3));
RoofA = str2double(dlgbox(4));

m = tand(RoofA);

h = figure;
set(h,'name','Simple AutoCAD House','numbertitle','off')

xlabel('x'),ylabel('y'),zlabel('z')
title('Simple AutoCAD House')
colormap white

%% Base/Floor

[xB,yB] = ndgrid(0:1:BaseL, 0:1:BaseW);
zB = (xB*0);
surf(xB,yB,zB,'FaceColor','k')
hold on

%% Walls

%Front Wall (w/Door opening)
[xFW,zFW] = ndgrid(0:1:BaseL, 0:1:WallH);
yFW = (xFW*0);
yFW(xFW>.4*BaseL & xFW<.6*BaseL & zFW<.8*WallH) = nan;
surf(xFW,yFW,zFW);
hold on

%Back Wall
[xBW,zBW] = ndgrid(0:.5:BaseL, 0:.5:WallH);
yBW = (xBW*0)+BaseW;
surf(xBW,yBW,zBW);

%Right Wall
[yRW,zRW] = ndgrid(0:.5:BaseW, 0:.5:WallH);
xRW = (yRW*0)+BaseL;
surf(xRW,yRW,zRW);

%Left Wall
[yLW,zLW] = ndgrid(0:.5:BaseW, 0:.5:WallH);
xLW = (yLW*0);
xLW(yLW>.25*BaseW & yLW<.75*BaseW & zLW>.5*WallH & zLW<.7*WallH) = nan;
surf(xLW,yLW,zLW);

%% Roof

%Left Panel
[xLP,yLP] = ndgrid(0:.5:(BaseL/2), 0:.5:BaseW);
zLP = (m*xLP)+WallH;
surf(xLP,yLP,zLP)
hold on

%Right Panel
[xRP,yRP] = ndgrid((BaseL/2):.5:BaseL, 0:.5:BaseW);
zRP = (-m*xRP)+(WallH+m*BaseL);
surf(xRP,yRP,zRP)

%% Roof Triangles

%Front Triangle
[xFT,zFT] = ndgrid(0:.25:BaseL, WallH:.25:(m*BaseL/2)+WallH);
yFT = 0*xFT;
yFT(zFT>(m*xFT+WallH)) = nan;
yFT(zFT>(-m*xFT+(m*BaseL+WallH))) = nan;
surf(xFT,yFT,zFT)

%Back Triangle
[xBT,zBT] = ndgrid(0:.25:BaseL, WallH:.25:(m*BaseL/2)+WallH);
yBT = (xBT*0)+BaseW;
yBT(zBT>(m*xBT+WallH)) = nan;
yBT(zBT>(-m*xBT+(m*BaseL+WallH))) = nan;
surf(xBT,yBT,zBT)

%% Door

[xD,zD] = ndgrid(.4*BaseL:.5:.6*BaseL, 0:.5:.8*WallH);
yD = xD*0;
door = surf(xD,yD,zD,'FaceColor','g');

%% Windows

%Left Window
[yLWin,zLWin] = ndgrid(.25*BaseW:.5:.75*BaseW, .5*WallH:.5:.75*WallH);
xLWin = (yLWin*0);
surf(xLWin,yLWin,zLWin,'FaceAlpha',.25,'FaceColor','b')
%% Desk and chair

%desktop
[xDT,yDT] = ndgrid(.8*BaseL:.5:.99*BaseL, .7*BaseW:.5:.99*BaseW);
zDT = (0*xDT);
surf(xDT,yDT,zDT,'FaceColor','r')

%DeskNear
[xDN,zDN] = ndgrid(.8*BaseL:.5:BaseL, 0:.5:.25*WallH);
yDN=(0*zDN)
surf(xDN,yDN,zDN,'FaceColor','r')

%% Door Opening

k = waitforbuttonpress;
if k == 0
    delete(door)

end
```

Comment: using `surf` this way to draw the house is not the most efficient way... You could use `patch` instead (think specifying vertices and then draw the faces by connecting vertices)

Answer (score 1):

The `ZData` property of a surface, is the z coordinate for each point in the surface. In your example, you set it to the right size by making it the same size as your `XData` and `YData`; however, the way you construct your `ZData` is a little off. You essentially do this:

```
zDT = (0 * xDT);
```

What this effectively does, is forces the z coordinate of every point in the mesh to be 0 (i.e. on the floor). This is why the desk top simply sits on the floor, and also why the side of the desk sits on the side of the wall (`y = 0`).

To fix this, you want to instead calculate what the values should actually be rather than setting them to zero.

#### Desktop

The nice thing is that the z value for the entire desktop is actually a constant for the whole surface since it's parallel to the floor. You define what the height of the desktop is when you create the side of the desk.

```
[xDN, zDN] = ndgrid(.8*BaseL:.5:BaseL, 0:.5:.25*WallH);
```

Here you're saying the height of the desk is `0.25 * WallH` rounded to the previous `0.5` (because of your step size). So we want to set the `ZData` of the desktop to be *that* value (the max of `zDN`) and we can multiply that value by a matrix of ones the size of the `XData` to make it the right size.

```
zDT = max(zDN(:)) * ones(size(xDT));
```

#### Side of Desk

For the side of the desk, the issue isn't the `ZData` anymore, it's now the `YData`. As it currently is, you have it set to all zeros so it get's stuck to the wall at `y = 0`.

```
yDN = (0 * zDN);
```

Again, we want the y value to be constant for the whole side of the desk. We can compute what this y value is by using the minimum y value from the desk top (again, making sure it's the right size by using a matrix of ones).

```
yDN = min(yDT(:)) * ones(size(xDN));
```

#### Summary

We can make those two changes and this makes the bottom portion of your code look something like this.

```
%desktop
[xDT,yDT] = ndgrid(.8*BaseL:.5:.99*BaseL, .7*BaseW:.5:.99*BaseW);
[xDN,zDN] = ndgrid(.8*BaseL:.5:BaseL, 0:.5:.25*WallH);

zDT = max(zDN(:)) * ones(size(xDT));
surf(xDT,yDT,zDT,'FaceColor','r')

%DeskNear
yDN = min(yDT(:)) * ones(size(xDN));
surf(xDN,yDN,zDN,'FaceColor','r')
```

If we apply that, we get the desktop off of the floor and the side of the desk where it belongs.

[image]

As Amro said in the comment to your post, it will likely be much easier to draw this sort of thing using [`patch`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/patch.html) rather than `surf` as it gives you a great deal more flexibility as far as shapes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my version of the house :)

Code should be easy to follow. Note that I'm using the `patch` function instead.

```
% input measurements
BaseL = 30;
BaseW = 40;
WallH = 15;
RoofA = 30;

% colors
m = tand(RoofA);
clr = hsv(10);
clf

% floor
patch([0 1 1 0].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 0 0 0].*WallH, clr(1,:));

% front wall (w/ door opening)
patch([1 1 0 0 0.4 0.4 0.6 0.6].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0].*BaseW, ...
    [0 1 1 0 0 0.8 0.8 0].*WallH, clr(2,:));

% back wall
patch([0 1 1 0].*BaseL, ...
    [1 1 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 0 1 1].*WallH, clr(3,:));

% right wall
patch([1 1 1 1].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 1 1 0].*WallH, clr(4,:));

% left wall (w/ window opening)
patch([0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 0.5 0.5 0.25 0.25 0.75 0.75 0.5 0.5 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 1 1 0.7 0.7 0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7 1 1 0].*WallH, clr(5,:));

% roof left/right panels
patch([0 0.5 0.5 0].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 1 1 0].*(m*BaseL/2)+WallH, clr(6,:));
patch([1 0.5 0.5 1].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 1 1 0].*(m*BaseL/2)+WallH, clr(7,:));

% roof front/back triangles
patch([0 1 0.5].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 0].*BaseW, ...
    [0 0 1].*(m*BaseL/2)+WallH, clr(8,:));
patch([0 1 0.5].*BaseL, ...
    [1 1 1].*BaseW, ...
    [0 0 1].*(m*BaseL/2)+WallH, clr(9,:));

% door
hDoor = patch([0.4 0.6 0.6 0.4].*BaseL, ...
    [0 0 0 0].*BaseW, ...
    [0 0 0.8 0.8].*WallH, 'k', 'FaceAlpha',0.75);

% window on left wall
hWin = patch([0 0 0 0].*BaseL, ...
    [0.25 0.75 0.75 0.25].*BaseW, ...
    [0.5 0.5 0.7 0.7].*WallH, 'k', 'FaceAlpha',0.75);

% table inside
patch([0.8 0.99 0.99 0.8].*BaseL, ...
    [0.7 0.7 0.99 0.99].*BaseW, ...
    [0.2 0.2 0.2 0.2].*WallH, clr(10,:));
patch([0.8 0.99 0.99 0.8].*BaseL, ...
    [0.7 0.7 0.7 0.7].*BaseW, ...
    [0.01 0.01 0.2 0.2].*WallH, clr(10,:));
patch([0.8 0.99 0.99 0.8].*BaseL, ...
    [0.99 0.99 0.99 0.99].*BaseW, ...
    [0.01 0.01 0.2 0.2].*WallH, clr(10,:));

% 3D view
axis([0 BaseL 0 BaseW 0 WallH*2]), axis vis3d
view(3), grid on
xlabel('X'), ylabel('Y'), zlabel('Z')
title('Simple AutoCAD House')

% animate door/window transparencies
t = linspace(-pi,pi,20);
anim = @(t) 1-(tanh(t)+1)/2;  % smooth function from 1 to 0
for i=1:numel(t)
    set([hDoor,hWin], 'FaceAlpha',anim(t(i)))
    pause(0.1)
end
```

[image: house]

There is a small animation at the end, where the door and window go from tinted to clear. Hope you like it!

Comment: note there in the end we used values like 0.99 and 0.01, a small correction to avoid bleeding artifacts, where surfaces appear on the other side of the wall..